# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Worklight deployment fails on SUSE Linux using a remote database

Tags: suse, connection-reset

I'm trying to deploy a war file to websphere through worklight using suse linux and a remote database.

When I tried to deploy the war file using a remote database(I'm using oracle to test), I'm getting the following error:

```
GetSQLQueryResult failed with error code java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at com.ibm.worklight.install.helper.GetSQLQueryResult.main(GetSQLQueryResult.java:68)  

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
```

I can access the remote machine database from the machine where worklight is installed.

Also, if I use the same WAR file on a local database on SUSE Linux, or use a remote database on another OS(Windows for example), the app is deployed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right with the question description...

1. You do not deploy .war files to Worklight
2. Worklight, in a remote server, is comprised of a Java EE .jar file, deployed to the  application server (WAS/Liberty profile, Tomcat)
3. A .war file, in Worklight, is a Java web app containing server-related artifacts required for running your application (generated by the Studio/CLI tool); you deploy this .war file to the application server where Worklight Server is deployed to

That said,
A connection reset means there is a general network issue and is not related to Worklight itself.

It sounds like a network issue with the specific machine running Suse Linux.
- Check firewall settings, timeout values, blocked ports...